# How do I store private app data on Google Drive with my iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I have an iOS app that has a local database. I'd like to back that up for users who choose to sign in with Google. The web (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata) and android (https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder) have guides on how to do this, but I can't find a similar one for iOS. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have code to upload a file to the user's Drive account, it is very easy to switch to uploading into the private app folder instead.  When making the `Files.insert` call, the file will be added to all of the folders listed in the `parents[]` array.  (If this array is empty, by default the file is added to the `root` folder.)  To upload the file into the private app data folder, simply set the `parents[]` array to `appfolder`.  You have to do this at the same time as uploading the file, because once it has been uploaded the file can't be moved between the user's drive and your app's private data folder.

(Note:  you may need to use the regular REST API to do this, because Google's [Drive API for iOS](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/) docs do not show any methods for actually uploading a new file to Drive.)

Comment: The reference guide in the iOS section is the REST API (from https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client). See https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_query_drive for methods

Comment: I'm not an iOS dev and so the interface docs look very bizarre to me, so perhaps you could point me to the method which allows a new file to be created?  I only see stuff like e.g. `queryForFilesPatchWithObject` that updates *existing* files in Drive.

Comment: Looks like the reference docs have a layout issue and it's omitting a few methods (or, more precisely, rendering them in the wrong area...)

See https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files for an example of a basic upload.

Answer (score 0):

Check this how this is working for me in swift 4.2 and above:

```
let googleDrive: GTLRDrive_File = GTLRDrive_File()
    googleDrive.name = "name.json"
    googleDrive.parents = ["appDataFolder"]
    let uploadParam: GTLRUploadParameters = GTLRUploadParameters(data: data, mimeType: "application/json")
    uploadParameters.shouldUploadWithSingleRequest = true;
    let queryDrive: GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate.query(withObject: metadata, uploadParameters: uploadParam)
    queryDrive.fields = "id"
    self.service.executeQuery(queryDrive) { (result, response, error) in
        if let file = response as? GTLRDrive_File {
            if (error == nil) {
                print(file.identifier)
               /// your code here
            } else {
                // handle error part
            }
        }
        else {
           //handle exception part 
        }
    }
```

"data" the json data  you get this like below

```
let param = [["key": "value"], ["key": "value"], ["key": "value"]]
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: .prettyPrinted)
```